# Implementing a Semaphore with std::mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

As a learning exercise, I'm just trying to make a `Semaphore` class using `std::mutex` and a few other things provided by the C++ standard.  My semaphore should allow as many `readLock()` as needed, however a `writeLock()` can only be acquired after all reads are unlocked.

```
//Semaphore.h
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class Semaphore{
public:
    Semaphore();
    void readLock(); //increments the internal counter
    void readUnlock(); //decrements the internal counter
    void writeLock(); //obtains sole ownership.  must wait for count==0 first
    void writeUnlock(); //releases sole ownership.
    int count; //public for debugging
private:
    std::mutex latch;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk;
    std::condition_variable cv;
};

//Semaphore.cpp
#include "Semaphore.h"
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Semaphore::Semaphore() : lk(latch,std::defer_lock) { count=0; }
void Semaphore::readLock(){ 
    latch.lock();
    ++count;
    latch.unlock();
    cv.notify_all(); //not sure if this needs to be here?
}
void Semaphore::readUnlock(){
    latch.lock();
    --count;
    latch.unlock();
    cv.notify_all(); //not sure if this needs to be here?
}
void Semaphore::writeLock(){
    cv.wait(lk,[this](){ return count==0; }); //why can't std::mutex be used here?
}
void Semaphore::writeUnlock(){ 
    lk.unlock();
    cv.notify_all();
}
```

My test program will `writeLock()` the semaphore, start a bunch of threads, and then release the semaphore.  Immediately afterwards, the main thread will attempt to `writeLock()` the semaphore again.  The idea is that when the semaphore becomes unlocked, the threads will `readLock()` it and prevent the main thread from doing anything until they all finish.  When they all finish and release the semaphore, then the main thread can acquire access again.  I realize this may not necessarily happen, but it's one of the cases I'm looking for.

```
//Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "Semaphore.h"

using namespace std;

Semaphore s;

void foo(int n){
    cout << "Thread Start" << endl;
    s.readLock();
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(n));
    cout << "Thread End" << endl;
    s.readUnlock();
}

int main(){
    std::srand(458279);
    cout << "App Launch" << endl;
    thread a(foo,rand()%10),b(foo,rand()%10),c(foo,rand()%10),d(foo,rand()%10);

    s.writeLock();
    cout << "Main has it" << endl;

    a.detach();
    b.detach();
    c.detach();
    d.detach();

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
    cout << "Main released it" << endl;
    s.writeUnlock();

    s.writeLock();
    cout << "Main has it " << s.count << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
    cout << "Main released it" << endl;
    s.writeUnlock();

    cout << "App End" << endl;

    system("pause"); //windows, sorry
    return 0;
}
```

The program throws an exception saying "unlock of unowned mutex".  I think the error is in `writeLock()` or `writeUnlock()`, but I'm not sure.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: There was a `std::defer_lock` missing when initializing `lk` in the constructor, however it didn't fix the error I was getting.  As mentioned in the comment, this isn't a semaphore and I apologize for the confusion.  To reiterate the problem, here is the output that I get (things in parenthesis are just my comments and not actually in the output):

```
App Launch
Thread Start
Thread Start
Main has it
Thread Start
Thread Start
Thread End (what?)
Main released it
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\thr\mutex.c(131): unlock of unowned mutex
Thread End
Thread End
Thread End
```

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a "reader-writer lock" as opposed to a more general "semaphore".

Comment: @CoryNelson I think you are right, but is there a subtle hint to the solution from that comment that I'm missing, or is that just semantics?

Comment: Solution to which problem? Do you want to implement a semaphore or a reader-writer lock?

Comment: It's not "just semantics." A semaphore allows N clients to acquire it concurrently. It's typically used to limit the number of concurrent clients that have access to a resource. A reader-writer lock allows any number of clients to acquire a read lock OR a single client to acquire the write lock. They are two fundamentally different things. Calling a reader-writer lock a semaphore and expecting others to understand what you mean is like calling a beer a football and then wondering why we would want to punt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely not a "semaphore".

Your `Semaphore` constructor acquires the lock on `latch` right away, then you unlock it twice because `writeUnlock()` calls `lk.unlock()` and the next call to `writeLock()` tries to wait on a condition variable with an unlocked mutex, which is undefined behaviour, then you the next call to `writeUnlock()` tries to unlock an unlocked mutex, which is also undefined behaviour.

Are you sure the constructor should lock the mutex right away? I think you want to use `std::defer_lock` in the constructor, and then lock the mutex in `writeLock()`.

Comment: Ahh yeah my original code had the `std::defer_lock` but I don't know why it didn't make it into the question code.  I'll edit that now.

Comment: That's not enough to fix it, now the first call to `writeLock()` will be trying to wait using a mutex that isn't owned, and the first call to `writeUnlock()` will be undefined behaviour.  When you call `cv.wait()` the first thing it does is unlock the mutex, so it has to be locked before the call!